# C# - Unit testing a WebApi controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am used to test Web controllers in Java in which a real request is being sent to the controller even under a unit test.

When it comes to C# the doc I am seeing like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api) or [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api/) it seems to check the call workflow to the controller methods but not an entire http message workflow.

In particular, say i have the following controller:

```
public class SessionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpDelete]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IHttpActionResult))]
    [Route("api/v1/sessions/{session-id}")]
    [ActionName("stop_session")]
    [ValidateModel]
    public IHttpActionResult StopSession([FromUri(Name = "session-id")] Guid sessionId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Stopping session {sessionId}");

        SessionRepository.Instance.Remove(sessionId);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If i create the following unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestStopSession()
    {
        SessionController controller = new SessionController()
        {
            Request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/api/v1/zada")
            }
        };
        controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

        var res = controller.StopSession(new Guid());

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(res, typeof(OkResult));
    }
```

As you can see, in test I am putting a different URL and even a different method and still the unit test passes successfully.

What is the way to unit test the entire HTTP workflow?

Comment: Well, by definition, testing the “entire HTTP workflow” wouldn’t actually be a unit test. The examples you’ve given are unit tests, what you are asking how to do is usually called integration testing, not unit testing. The way to do that would be to actually startup the WebAPI server and have your tests make real HTTP requests to it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test?

Comment: Testing entire http flow is an integration test. That can be done using test server.

Answer (score 0):

I this case your are testing the unit `TestStopSession` from the `SessionController`, and not any routing, validation etc. I think that's OK for an unit test, as you need to test one unit at once.

You're calling the method TestStopSession, so there isn't even a routing take place here.

> What is the way to unit test the entire HTTP workflow?

You need an integration or system test then. You could spin up a HTTP listener and then do the raw request.

But keep in mind, don't write to many integration / system tests. Be sure to know the test pyramid

[image]

Comment: I have been in several projects and it's always much more productive to test the web controller in a unit test environment. And languages usually permit it. There are a few advantages to this: a) it tests the json deserialization code b) it tests the routing is setup correctly c) It is much faster to test it than putting up an entire client server setup. That is just to name a few.

Comment: Also, if testing the controller is just calling its functions it's unclear why the doc(look at the link above) asks for setting up the URL and the HTTP method, even if i just create a controller without the setting the request and method and test it that works for me. This means there is a way to test URL and HTTP method which is really the question i am asking.